# Ruby on OS X 10.9 Ignoring gems because extensions are not built

Tags: macos, ruby

Every few days this will happen when doing various things in Ruby CLI (notably, using the `knife` utility for Chef) on OS X (unable to replicate in other environments; Linux, FreeBSD, etc.):

```
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt-3.1.7
Ignoring bigdecimal-1.2.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bigdecimal-1.2.5
Ignoring ffi-yajl-1.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine ffi-yajl-1.1.0
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.5 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers-1.2.5
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers-1.2.4
Ignoring pg-0.17.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg-0.17.1
Ignoring psych-2.0.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine psych-2.0.6
Ignoring sqlite3-1.3.9 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine sqlite3-1.3.9
```

And while it's a simple fix, it keeps happening. Has anyone come across this before?

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently switched to from `rvm` to `chruby` and ran `gem update --system`, thats when the issue began occurring for me. After that, anytime I ran bundle I was slaughtered with the same warnings. Still not sure which caused the issue.

`Ignoring curb-0.8.6 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine curb-0.8.6`

Not sure what fixed it, but I did 2 things and the warning disappeared:

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler

gem install curb
```

Comment: Oddly enough, it started for me when I switched from the OS X-bundled Ruby to RVM. Generally, it clears on its own after a few days or if I open a new session (which is sort of a hassle when it occurs midday). I generally have to reinstall whatever I'm using at a given time, and that is usually Knife.

Comment: it was happening for dozens of gems on my machine. i think they just had to be rebuilt

Comment: For myself, I had to uninstall each gem that it was giving a warning for and then reinstall with `bundle install`

Comment: "I was slaughtered" - wow.

Comment: Whatever I try I get `You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory`, those issues started on their own, I'm not even using ruby for all I know. But I get errors about extensions not built for `clocale-0.0.3` whenever I start a new shell

Answer (score 63):

In my case I start to see this errors after installing `rvm`

I resolve such problem with: `gem pristine --all`

Comment: what a useful command

Comment: This worked... But I have no idea why

Comment: uninstalling bundler and installing did not work. But this one worked! Thanks!

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

This problem occurs, if a gem was compiled against a different libruby as the currently running. For example, if one uses a ruby located in his home directory with chruby and installs gems to ~/.gem/ruby, but runs a script which calls /usr/bin/ruby, which reuses the gems installed there. In this case `gem pristine --all` will not help, because the gems can be linked only against one ruby version.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you! I was getting that error when running "rails s". I switched to "bundle exec rails s" and the problem vanished.

Comment: This answer is right. If the problem happens in a Rails repository where gems are saved in `vendor/bundle`, just delete them with `rm -rf vendor/bundle` and reinstall them with `bundle install`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried `gem pristine --all` till I was blue in the face and now I know why it didn't work...

Comment: Note to self - see my newer answer below for more details: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/436672/79496

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by:

```
rvm get stable
```

https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3348

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on MacOs Sierra:

```
xcode-select --install
gem install nokogiri
```

I already had installed the entire xcode prior to running the above commands, but I had to do this anyways, perhaps because the first script updates some internal libraries/dependencies.

Comment: This is what I were looking for MacOS Sierra solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running "gem pristine --all" for the right version of ruby.  If /usr/bin/ruby is being called... use "/usr/bin/gem pristine --all".  This is not obvious if you're using rvm and you have 10 versions of ruby installed.

This fixed my problem for a day and then it came back.

What seems to be a more permanent solution is to do "rvm reset" to have the default ruby be the installed OSX version /usr/bin/ruby and /usr/bin/gem.  If I want to use a newer version of ruby for a project I use .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset in the project root directory to explicitly set the version of ruby I want to use.  Not ideal... but it should make this error go away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

`rvm get stable`

`sudo gem pristine --all`

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to rails so this might be completely misguided advice but since none of the other solutions worked for me I thought I'd share mine.

Mic92 and Gerry put me on the right track: I was using `rails s` which can cause errors because it runs a rails version that can be a different version than the project's.

I tried to connect with `bin/rails server`, I got a different error (missing gems) so I ran `bundle install`

At this point I got a third error ("incompatible library version"), which `spring stop` cured.

Then I ran `rails generate controller` again, spring restarted and everything worked (I cried a little).

Answer (score 0):

What this error means is that you cannot use the current version of the gem. It was installed with an older Ruby executable, and/or other system utilities and binaries have changed, making it such that you need to completely reinstall the gem again over from scratch. This happened to me when I migrated from Ruby 2.5.3 to Ruby 2.7.1. I had carried over all my gems from the previous version (via `rvm migrate`), but they were now broken. All my gems had to be rebuilt according to the 2.7.1 dependencies. So I had to completely remove all my gems via `rvm gemset empty ruby-2.7.1`. When that happens, it will print out a list of all your gems which were installed. Copy & paste that output into a safe file, which you can look back at again later to reinstall the gems you need to install a truly clean environment for your new Ruby version.